# I wanted to extract the entire "Journey History" of all contacts using REST/SOAP API, facing issue for more than 10K records, Any solution?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, marketingcloudapi, sfmc-business-unit

I was trying to retrieve **JourneyHistory** using below API

**https://xxxxxxxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/interaction/v1/interactions/journeyhistory/search?$page=2&$pageSize=5000**

The problem I am facing here is I am not able to retrieve more than 10 K records. Suppose there is total Count of 80 k and I am trying with page=3 and pagesize=5000, it gives me **Page and page size must be greater than 0. Record access cannot exceed 10,000th item** error message. Is there any rest/soap api which I can use to retrieve entire journeyhistory records ?

Comment: Did you get answer to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the page size, you can specify the `start` and `end` dates in the payload as illustrated [here](https://www.forcetalks.com/blog/saving-journey-history-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud/).  That should help you plow through all of the results.

```
POST /interaction/v1/interactions/journeyhistory/search?$pageSize=500&$page=1 HTTP/1.1
Host: YOURTENANTHERE.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Content-Type: application/json
{
     "start": "2023-01-24T00:00:00.000Z"
    ,"end": null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem from @zuzannamj and I are having is that we cannot write a loop to scroll through pages if the total records are > 10k.

The value of page * pagesize seemed to be 10000 max. So if you write $page=2&$pageSize=5000 it will return a response but if $page=2&$pageSize=5001  it will return an error. The error message is wrong which caused the confusion because page and page size are already > 0:

Error message for $page=2&$pageSize=5001

> Page and page size must be greater than 0. Record access cannot exceed
> 10,000th item.

What @zuzannamj and I are trying to achieve is depicted below, but it seemed impossible now because of the above limit.

> '/interaction/v1/interactions/journeyhistory/search?$page='+var+'&$pageSize=10000'
>
> var ++;

@Adam Spriggs proposed to break the query down into smaller time window to reduce the response size, however, imagine a journey with 20000 records in entry data extension entering at once, then we can't have a result that way.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/203978)