# Is there a way to automate (API, SSJS script, etc.) stopping the journey when the last contact exits?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, ssjs, automationstudio

I am currently working on a case where I need to work on automating to stop the journey when the last contact exits it.

It would be much easier to just manually stop the journey.
However, I need to build an automation process if it is possible.
I tried looking up for possible methods but couldn't find much.

If anybody can share their experience, it would be a huge help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could automate an SSJS activity to make two API calls to the interaction route: 1st to get the [journey history](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/11/27/get-journey-history-by-filtering-the-definition-id-via-api/) to check if all contacts have finished the journey and 2nd to [stop the journey](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/postStopInteractionById.html) if needed

Comment: Why do you need to stop a journey like this?

Comment: This is upon the customer's request. Regarding the journey history, I have found that it is limited to retrieve the last 30 days data and also have seen a case where it is limited to retrieve up to 10k contacts. For instance, if the number of contact exceeds 10k, then I assume that there is no other possible method to stop the journey automatically? <https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/11/27/get-journey-history-by-filtering-the-definition-id-via-api/> <https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/323288/i-wanted-to-extract-the-entire-journey-history-of-all-contacts-using-rest-soap>

Comment: Logical question first: How do you know that a contact is "the last one", i.e. that there will be no new injections? The journey itself doesn't do the injection, so to me the first key problem would to monitor / log  the logics that push records in (SQL, API) centrally. If you tackle that, then with some assumptions / conventions, it could be super simple. assess a max journey duration X , say, 3 months. If the last injection is older than X, the journey is considered dead and turned off. If you need something more specific, then sure you need to monitor additional things for dynamic logics.